# What is different between "string" and "string?" in new version of c#?

Tags: c#, string

`String` is already nullable. then what is different between "string" and "string?"

For example:

```
public class ClassA
{
                 // should we use here?
   public void Method(string? name)
   {
                        // should we use here?
      var dic = new Dictionary<string,string?>();
      // logic here
   }
}
```

Comment: ...as opposed to?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

Comment: why would you..?

Comment: _"`String` is already nullable"_ - **no it isn't** (unless you have NRT disabled). `String` is non-nullable, `String?` is nullable. When using a `String` parameter you should also add a precondition: `if( name is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));` or use `!!` if you're using .NET 7.

Comment: i know that @Dia but Refactor tool made it ?.  if it is not in parameter use in method then?

Comment: @PradeepKumar What "refactoring tool" made the change and why?

Comment: visual studio 2022

Comment: Does your .csproj project have `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in it?

Comment: Maybe but i am asking is not how it came. My Question is should we use string? or not and why?

Comment: if yes then When we should use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A question about how to use nullable reference types seems like it would have been asked before, but I can't find a good existing answer on stackoverflow to reference.

---

**What are nullable reference types?**

Nullable reference types were added to help avoid null reference exceptions. Unlike nullable value types, these are entirely "compile time" analysis. This is important to note because the `type` of a nullable reference type is the same as the type it is referring to, for example `string` and `string?`. This is different from value types where `int` and `int?` are different types (`System.Int32` and `Nullable<System.Int32>` respectively).

**When should I use nullable reference types?**

When you want static code analysis to help avoid null reference exceptions. There will be no runtime difference if you use "standard" reference types as the analysis is only performed at compile time (or as you are writing code within Visual Studio).

**How do I enable nullable reference types?**

Nullable reference types are available since C#8.0.

These can be enabled by adding the following to your .csproj file:

```xml
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Beginning with .NET 6, new Visual Studio projects include the `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` element in all project templates.

---

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) for further details.

Comment: Posted as community wiki, I probably got some technical details wrong, I'm not attached to anything please improve as you see fit!